# How to trigger camera from a remote html page loaded in childbrowser in ios ?

Tags: iphone

I need to access camera from a remote html page. I load this html page through child browser . Need to open camera or any native view on a button click on html file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sure if this is the best/most elegant possibility, but it should work:

By click on button load an specific URL.
The `UIWebView` has delegate methods to inform you, when a page finished loading.

In the `– webViewDidFinishLoad:` method check if the loaded URL was your specific button URL, if `YES` show camera/any other native view.